# Xubuntu 12.04 UI glitches

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, gui, xfce

I'm having some strange problems with Thunderbird and Chrome in Xubuntu 12.04 XFCE 4.10 (installed from PPA).

Some UI elements from both windows sometimes are drawn on each other, no matter which window is active at the moment.

Not sure what I should do - report a bug to XFCE, or Thunderbird, or Chrome? Other ideas?

[image: strange UI problems]

Comment: xfce 4.10? are you using the xfce 4.10 ppa or have you just mistyped the xfce version??

Comment: I'm using 4.10 from PPA

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Report the bug to the PPA maintainers.

Comment: solved by removing XFCE and installing gnome-fallback